# Select row in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a gridview with an index. It is not the currently selected gridview row, but the previously selected one I have saved, how do I select a gridview row by the index? THis is in c sharp

Comment: how do you bind your data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this

```
GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[previouslySavedIndex];
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
String value =  GridView1.Rows[index].Cells[0].Text;
```

you can do a for loop according to your columns count